# Inconsistent behavior in Scala CPS framework

Tags: scala, continuations, continuation-passing, delimited-continuations

I'm trying to build a coroutine framework to enable batch data fetching by stepping through each data-dependent function in parallel. Here is what I have so far: http://pastie.org/7147798

1. **This doesn't work**

   ```scala
   def get(id: Long) = reset {
     // Is it not already cached?
     if (!cached.isDefinedAt(id)) {
       // Store the ID we want to fetch.
       queued += id
       // Come back later...
       shift { fetch[Object]() } : Seq[Any] @cps[ExecState[Object]]
     }
     // We should have the ID fetched now.
     Result(cached(id))
   }
   ```

   **I get the following error**

   ```scala
   ashoat@ashoatmbp [~/project]# scala -P:continuations:enable Loader.scala
   /Users/ashoat/project/Loader.scala:134: error: type mismatch;
    found   : Unit
    required: Any @util.continuations.package.cps[Main.$anon.Loader.ExecState[Main.$anon.Loader.Object]]
         if (!cached.isDefinedAt(id)) {
         ^
   one error found
   ```

   **This works**

   ```scala
   def get(id: Long) = reset {
     // Is it not already cached?
     if (!cached.isDefinedAt(id)) {
       // Store the ID we want to fetch.
       queued += id
       // Come back later...
       shift { fetch[Object]() } : Seq[Any] @cps[ExecState[Object]]
       // We should have the ID fetched now.
       Result(cached(id))
     } else {
       // We should have the ID fetched now.
       Result(cached(id))
     }
   }
   ```
2. **This doesn't work**

   ```scala
   val getFive = reset {
     if (true) {
       Result(5)
     } else {
       val seq: Seq[Any] = shift { fetch[Int](Object.get(15181990251L)) }
       val Seq(obj: Object) = seq
       Result(obj.fields("test").toInt)
     }
   }
   ```

   **I get the following error**

   ```scala
   ashoat@ashoatmbp [~/project]# scala -P:continuations:enable Loader.scala
   /Users/ashoat/project/Loader.scala:170: error: cannot cps-transform expression new this.Loader.Result[Int](5): type arguments [this.Loader.Result[Int],this.Loader.Result[Int],Nothing] do not conform to method shiftUnit's type parameter bounds [A,B,C >: B]
       Result(5)// : Result[Int] @cps[Result[Int]]
             ^
   one error found
   ```

   **This works**

   ```scala
   val getFive = reset {
     if (true) {
       Result(5) : Result[Int] @cps[Result[Int]]
     } else {
       val seq: Seq[Any] = shift { fetch[Int](Object.get(15181990251L)) }
       val Seq(obj: Object) = seq
       Result(obj.fields("test").toInt)
     }
   }
   ```

   **But I get the following warning**

   ```scala
   ashoat@ashoatmbp [~/project]# scala -P:continuations:enable Loader.scala
   /Users/ashoat/project/Loader.scala:170: warning: expression (new this.Loader.Result[Int](5): this.Loader.Result[Int]) is cps-transformed unexpectedly
       Result(5) : Result[Int] @cps[Result[Int]]
                 ^
   one warning found
   8
   ```

Comment: Why do you expect "to have the ID fetched now"? The way I read your code, I see that `Result(...)` is after the *shift* block and is also the last expression inside your *reset*. So I would expect `shift` to take a `Result[Int]` and compute another expression with it, that would be the value returned by the whole *reset* block.

Comment: @Ashoat Please, it would greatly help if you try to explain what you want to achieve. What does the fetch function do? It looks like you use shift as a call to an external procedure instead of a context shift. Don't want to sound rude, but I must ask if you are confident with the use of shift/reset.

Comment: @pagoda_5b: I've edited the question to add some more details including a link to the full source I have so far. My use of shift just passes the current state of the delimited reset block along with some specified dependencies into a function that transforms them into a single continuation, which is then returned to the caller of the reset block.

Comment: @huynhjl: The ID will be "fetched now" because between each shift "step" in the function a data fetch is executed by the function's caller.

Comment: @Ashoat link to the source improves the question greatly.

Comment: @Ashoat no clear solution now, but wondering how do the `shift` combines with being inside an `if` block... I know that other *flow control* stuff like `for` and `while` doesn't play friends with *delimited conts*. Q: what happens when you capture the `cont`? does it run up to the `else` block? goes over it? mess it up? Could you refactor to put the `reset` block inside the `if` and would it work? Just brainstorming here...

Answer (score 1):

Although I still don't quite understand *continuations* myself, as best as I can tell, the key issue in your example is that your code does not always supply a `shift` to the `reset`.

The compiler expects to find some `shift` nested inside the `reset`. It will then CPS transform the `shift` into a [`ControlContext][A, B, C]`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.util.continuations.ControlContext) and the code that happens after the `shift` into a `ControlContext.map` call.

Because you have an `if` statement, in the case where the *else* branch is taken, there is no nested `shift`:

```
reset {
  if (false) {
    shift { ... }
  } 
  Result(cached(id)) // no shift
}
```

Same with

```
reset {
  if (false) {
    shift { ... }
  } else {
    Result(cached(id)) // no shift
  }
}
```

That cannot be transformed into valid CPS code.

It seems you could have the reset inside the if branch or supply a trivial shift statement to the else branch:

```
if (!cached.isDefinedAt(id)) reset {
   shift { ... }
   Result(cached(id))
} else {
   Result(cached(id))
}

// or

reset {
  if (!cached.isDefinedAt(id)) {
    shift { ... }
    Result(cached(id))
  } else {
    shift[Result[Object], ExecState[Object], ExecState[Object]] { k => 
      Result(cached(id))
    }
  }
}
```

**Edit:** It does seems there is some inconsistencies on how the cps plugin infers the types. For example:

```
var b = false
def test[A](a: A) = reset {
  if (b) {
    a
  } else {
    shift{ (k: Unit => A) => k() }
    a
  }
}
```

Running compilation with the `-Xprint:selectivecps` options shows that the compiler infers the type as `Reset[A, Nothing]` then running the code will produce an error at runtime. If the *if* is reversed as:

```
var b = false
def test[A](a: A) = reset {
  if (b) {
    shift{ (k: Unit => A) => k() }
    a
  } else {
    a
  }
}
```

Then the compiler correctly infers `reset[A, A]`. If I provide the type parameters to `reset` like `test[A](a: A) = reset[A, A] {` then it works in both cases.

Maybe specifying the type parameters to `reset` and `shift` and also instead of using `Result(5)`, using the `shiftUnit[A, B, C]` method will help with reducing inconsistencies.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. It does seem like these issues only occur when there is a return path in the `reset` that doesn't pass through a `shift` block. However, this still doesn't explain why I'm getting the behavior that I am: computationally equivalent statements are compiling when written in one way and erroring when written in others. My suspicion is this this has to do with how type inference works with the continuations plugin, but I would like to understand exactly what's going wrong.

Comment: I think the compiler cps plugin fails to report code that is incorrect. When you says "it works", do you mean the code actually perform what it's supposed to do? Or it just compiles? My hunch is that it compiles but you will get a runtime error or incorrect behavior.

Comment: The code performs what it should... unless I reverse the if-else blocks, in which case it gives a runtime error. Very inconsistent behavior.